# Parse 24:00 AM datetime in R

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, posixct

I have some data with an unconventional date format for midnight. In the raw data, midnight is being treated as `"1/1/2018 24:00 AM"` instead of `"1/2/2018 00:00 AM"`. Why would anyone do this?!

I'd like to convert this character vector into a `POSIXct()` format.

Here is some example data:

```
datetime <- c("1/1/2018 11:00 PM", "1/1/2018 24:00 AM", "1/2/2018 01:00 AM")
```

The following code fails to parse midnight but does what I want otherwise:

```
as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
```

This returns the following:

```
[1] "2018-01-01 23:00:00 GMT" NA                        "2018-01-02 01:00:00 GMT"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to use `lubridate::mdy_hm` which parses `24:00 AM` correctly as `00:00 AM` on the next day.

```
library(lubridate)
mdy_hm(datetime)
#[1] "2018-01-01 23:00:00 UTC" "2018-01-02 00:00:00 UTC"
#[3] "2018-01-02 01:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: This works great! Glad to see there was an easy fix, thank you. So it seems like `lubridate` functions are a little more flexible in their ability to parse different datetime formats then?

Comment: @spacedSparking Yes, `lubridate` is great for these kind of operations, as it takes a lot of the work dealing with fringe cases/exceptions off your hands.